# Why does spring boot appear NoSuchMethodError and it's inside of the class JiraManager

Tags: spring-boot, jira-rest-api

What I'm trying to do is get the data from Jira using the api:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.MetadataRestClient.getIssueTypes()'
at com.vision.servlet.AdminController.getProjectTypes(AdminController.java:2994) ~[classes/:na]
at com.vision.servlet.AdminController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$80c23742.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue might be in the communication with the API provided by Atlassian,
You will find in the following link more details regarding Atlassian API
[JIRA Cloud Platform REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/)